# Asyncio "RuntimeError: Event loop is closed"

Tags: python, python-asyncio, discord.py

I'm trying to make a Discord Bot and it has to check an API every minute or so and then send a message to a channel.

But for some reason, the loop breaks and ends the task.
It's my first time using asyncio and discord.py

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bot.py", line 207, in <module>
    client.loop.run_forever()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/asyncio/base_events.py", line 407, in run_forever
    self._check_closed()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/asyncio/base_events.py", line 358, in _check_closed
    raise RuntimeError('Event loop is closed')
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
Task was destroyed but it is pending!
task: <Task pending coro=<my_background_task() running at bot.py:193> wait_for=<Future pending cb=[<TaskWakeupMethWrapper object at 0xb52dbd10>()]>>
```

The source code for the script is this one:
[bot.py](https://gist.github.com/dicamarques14/87d58260ec7024ed64475c28cafc57a5)

Just want to have my_background_task() to run forever, or at least restart if it breaks.

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50305670/edit) your post to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: What is your console outputs? You have a lot of debugging print lines, can you post the lines printed?

Comment: It seems that `client.run` already runs the event loop indefinitely, and closes it. That means that you needn't and can't call `run_forever` after it. Instead, remove all instances of `except: pass` from your code, so that you see the actual errors instead of sweeping them under the rug. This might prove useful in debugging the underlying problem that leads to  `client.run` exiting prematurely.

Answer (score 0):

Make the bot run the async task

```
async def bg():
    for i in range(3):
        print("Background tast")
        await asyncio.sleep(1)




@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Ready!")
    bot.loop.create_task(bg())
```